# Datatables row selection - Anonymous function on PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datatables, server-side, anonymous-function

I'm using this Datatables [example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html), on my server with a PHP version 5.2.

I know anonymous functions cannot be used, like the 'Server-side script' in the example on line 35, but I need some kind of solution for that, since I can't upgrade my server.

This is the problem:

`array(
    'db' => 'id',
    'dt' => 'DT_RowId',
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        // Technically a DOM id cannot start with an integer, so we prefix
        // a string. This can also be useful if you have multiple tables
        // to ensure that the id is unique with a different prefix
        return 'row_'.$d;
}),`

Does any one have a solution for that `function($d, $row)`?

Answer (score 0):

'Maybe you can use array_map:

array_map("function", array('db' => 'id', ...)),

then define function to do what you want to the 'formatter' element, but leaving all other elements as is.

I'll try to elaborate, here is the suggested code (I'm assuming that only $d is an integer, if not there may be another recognizer you could use instead of is_int()):

```
array_map(
  function($val) {$val = is_int($val) ? 'row_'.$d : $val}, 
  array('db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'DT_RowId','formatter' => $d)
)
```

Depending on which php version you are using, you may have to define a non-anonymous function.

Here is a working example which should work in 5.2:

```
<?php
  $d = 10;

  function func($val) {
    return is_int($val) ? 'row_'.$val : $val;}

  print_r(array_map(     
    "func", 
    array('db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'DT_RowId','formatter' => $d)
   ));
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array ( [db] => id [dt] => DT_RowId [formatter] => row_10 )
```

Comment: I'm getting this syntax error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in ...` corresponding to the function line.
And has I've already mentioned I can't use anonymous functions, since my server has a 5.2 PHP version, and can't be upgraded.